# Handling Document Updates without Unique Identifier in Laravel Pivot Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a Laravel project where I'm fetching product data from an API that includes associated documents. The documents are stored in a separate table with a pivot table (product_document) due to a many-to-many relationship between products and documents. The challenge I'm facing is that the API response lacks a unique identifier for the documents, and I need to determine whether a document should be updated or created for a given product.

API response example:

```
$productdata = [
    'id' => 757,
    'code' => 'tee',
    'name' => 'Long tee shirt',
    'supplier_productcode' => 'Penshoppe',
    'weight' => 5,
    'unit' => 0,
    'stocklevel' => 100,
    'min_stocklevel' => 0,
    'documents' => [
        [
            'name' => 'productDocs.PDF',
            'size' => 70984,
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'shirtDesign.PDF',
            'size' => 110868,
        ],
    ],
    'updated_at' => '2023-05-23 13:39:18',
];
```

The relevant portions of my code are as follows:

// Pivot Table (product_document)

- id = Primary key
- product_id = Foreign key for Product Table
- document_id = Foreign key for Document table

// Product Table

- id = Primary key
- api_id = ID from the API response

// Document Table

- id = Primary key
- name
- size

// Product Model

```
public function documents(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Document::class, 'product_document')->using(ProductDocument::class);
}
```

//Fetching and Updating

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
                    $product_lastUpdate = $product['updated_at'];

                    if (Carbon::parse($product_lastUpdate) == '2023-05-23 13:39:18') {
                     
                       // Code for updating or creating products
                        $upProduct = Product::updateOrCreate(
                            [
                                'api_id' => $product['id']
                            ],                    
                            [
                                'api_id' => $product['api_id'],
                                'code' => $product['code'],
                                'name' => $product['name'],
                                'supplier_productcode' => $product['supplier_productcode'],
                                'weight' => $product['weight'],
                                'unit' => $product['unit'],
                                'stocklevel' => $product['stocklevel'],
                                'min_stocklevel' => $product['min_stocklevel'],
                            ] 
                        );

                        // Code for updating or creating documents
                        foreach ($product['documents'] as $key => $document) {

                        // How to handle updates or creations here without a unique identifier?

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I've considered checking for changes in name and size attributes, but it seems insufficient. How can I approach this problem to accurately determine whether a document should be updated or a new one created?

I'm open to alternative solutions or suggestions on how to handle this situation more effectively. Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you check if there are documents in the API response, delete the old documents and then recreate the documents.

Comment: @KhayamKhan Indeed, I've considered implementing that idea. Nevertheless, the code is designed for automated data import with intervals and scheduling. I'm uncertain about its suitability given the many products and documents that must be fetched and updated.